# PHP email body background color not coloring whole mail

Tags: php, html, css, email

The background color only colors the first half of my email when I try to add background-color in my body.

```
$mail->Body =
  "<body style='background-color: #fbedde;'>
       <div style='width:800px; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
          <img src='cid:logo' width='40%' style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;'>
          <h1 style='color: #00a6a6; font-family: 'brandon_black'; letter-spacing: 2px; padding-bottom: 60px;'>COUPON CLAIMED</h1>
        <div style='padding-top:30px; width: 400px;float:left;'>
          <img src='cid:coupon' width='85%' style='padding-left: auto; padding-right: auto; border-radius: 2% !important; box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);'>
        </div>
        <div style='padding-top:15px; width: 400px; float:left; text-align: left; color: #00a6a6;'>
          <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>Claimed By:</h3>
          <h2 style='font-family: 'brandon_black'; letter-spacing: 1px;'>$usr_fname $usr_lname</h2>
          <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>$usr_contact</h3>
          <h3 style='font-weight: bold;'>$usr_member</h3><br>
          <h3>Please proceed to<h3>
          <a href='https://www.mywhitecard.ph/cms' style='color: #00a6a6; text-decoration: underline;'>https://www.mywhitecard.ph/cms</a>
          <h3>for scheduling of member.</h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>";
```

I added the css directly into the tags because the css styles dont get recognized if taken from a different file since this is an html email.

[image: 1]

I do not have any other background-color styles thats why I am questioning why the other half of my mail remains uncolored. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is an extra `div` at the end of the code which is an error and email clients might not like that, the last `div` before the closing `body`... not sure it that helps or not

Comment: that is not an extra div, its the end of the first div to put the whole email html inside

Comment: Sorry may bad. Could it be the font-family tag using `'`? - I pasted your code into a fiddle and it shows errors https://jsfiddle.net/70wsmnkx/

Comment: I don't think its the font family, the "COUPON CLAIMED"  has that font-family style but it gets colored by background-color

Comment: true... it is confusing. The jpeg screenshot, where is that rendered from?

Comment: I am using PHP for that:  $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../img/logo_header.png','logo');

Comment: So your `font-family: 'brandon_black'` uses `'` within a style tag opening with `'` which may close the style tag early, try replacing all the font-family `'` with `\"`

Comment: well the fix was not exactly like that but i only the moved the "font-family" on the end of the "style" and the background color fixed itself.

Comment: anyway thats for pointing out the font-family

Comment: Also `<h3>Please proceed to<h3>` should be closed properly